# Rails ajax Dynamic select

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

*Seems that the code is correct!*

so, someone could spare any information why the second(subcategories) partial did not update? Thank's

**I put on js:**

```
$(document).ready(function()  {
  return $(document).on('click', "input[type='radio'][name='product[gender_id]']", function(evt) {
    return $.ajax('update_category_select', {
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'script',
      data: {
        gender_id: $("input[type='radio'][name='product[gender_id]']:checked").val()
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        return console.log("AJAX Error: " + textStatus);
      },
      success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        return console.log("Dynamic state select OK!");
      }
    });
  });

  return $(document).on('change', '#categories_select', function(evt) {
    return $.ajax('update_subcategory_select', {
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'script',
      data: {
        category_id: $("#categories_select option:selected").val()
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        return console.log("AJAX Error: " + textStatus);
      },
      success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        return console.log("Dynamic state select OK!");
      }
    });

  });
});
```

**First Partial:**

```
$("#categories_select").empty().append("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => @categories)) %>")
```

*If the firt partial is updated update the second partial*

**Second partial:**

```
$("#subcategories_select").empty().append("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => @subcategories)) %>")
```

**Products Controller**

```
 @catagories = Category.where("gender_id = ?", params[:gender_id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end


 def update_subcategory_select


    @subcategories = Subcategory.where("category_id = ?", params[:category_id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

Comment: Where are you calling the partial updates?

Comment: @RicchPeck. thank's for your interest, i added in the product controller. 

i edited the question now.

 def update_category_select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `return` is used inside a function to return a value/expression and the following sentences are not executed.

In your javascript do you have something like:

```
function(){ //Document ready
  return 1; //Here you on click
  return 2; //Here you on change
}
```

So return 2 is never called. In your case, the event handler for 'change' is never attached so subcategories are not updated.

Just remove all `return` in your javascript code.